# Unreachable code in simple arithmetic function

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, unreachable-code

Upon compile, SBCL complains that `(mod number 10)` is unreachable in

```
(defun foo (number)
  (cond
    ((> number 10) (mod number 10))
    (t number)))
```

Why is this so?

The full compiler message:

```
; in: DEFUN FOO
;     (MOD NUMBER 10)
; --> LET IF AND IF IF PLUSP > 
; ==>
;   NUMBER
; 
; note: deleting unreachable code
```

Comment: I can't reproduce on SBCL or GNU CLISP. What version, and what command are you using to compile?

Comment: SBCL 1.4.5.debian. I'm using C-c C-c from within the SLIME environment v2.20

Comment: Very interesting. It *does* do that inside of SLIME, but when I load from the command line it doesn't. I wonder what warnings SLIME is enabling that aren't on by default.

Comment: Thanks for corroborating. Assuming SLIME is right that `(mod number 10)` can be deleted, I can't see how it would do that while maintaining the function of `foo`. Any ideas?

Comment: And how did it come up with `let if and if if plusp`?

Comment: After copy-pasting your code into an emacs buffer and sending the function definition to the REPL with C-c C-c, it works fine for me. I can't reproduce, but I am using Slime 2.26 with SBCL 2.0.10.

Comment: I should mention I'm using SBCL 1.4.5.debian on SLIME v2.26, so it makes sense I would get similar results to OP.

Comment: I suspect strongly that what you are seeing is deletion of code from whatever `(mod number 10)` has turned into, possibly based on the fact that the compiler knows a lot about the type of `number` at that point (it's a positive real).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the comments, it's most likely dead code elimination of code that `(mod number 10)` expanded to.
On SBCL 2.0.0 and later, I'm not able to reproduce the warning.

AKA Compiler 'bug'